# Friendly urls for profiles and search engine pollution

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, abuse, search-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could Stack Overflow be damaged by “URL poisoning”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67383/could-stack-overflow-be-damaged-by-url-poisoning)

Friendly URLs for profiles is a nice feature, however, there are at least 2 drawbacks:

#### Attacks on reputation problem

Friendly URLs can open the door to malevolent attacks on someone's reputation (as in "real world reputation").

Imagine you have this profile URL:
*http://something.stackexchange.com/users/[id]/john-doe*

A malevolent person could create a [Google bomb attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_bomb) with this kind of URL:
*http://something.stackexchange.com/users/[id]/john-doe-**is-incompetent-liar***

This URL is still valid for a SE site: it just redirects to "john-doe" for instance.

#### SEO problem

I have a dozen accounts opened on different SE sites, all linked to my SO account.

Googling for my name showed first a bunch of URLs pointing to my profiles on different SE sites (most of which I use very rarely), showing even before my SO and Linkedin profiles!

A month ago I decided to change my name to a pseudonym on these (rarely used) SE profiles, trying to mitigate the problem.

And it didn't gelp. Google still keeps those URLs on top - it must consider them as still valid (because they technically are).

#### Proposed solution

Disable the friendly URL feature on profiles, allowing only 2 possible ways to access a profile:

1. *http://something.stackexchange.com/users/[id]/john-doe*
2. *http://something.stackexchange.com/users/[id]*

where *john-doe* is the **current** name of the profile owner. Any other URL "friendling" would trigger a 404 response.

Comment: What if someone linked to my profile as `/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff` and then I change my display name to `Rebecca`?  That's a broken link now.

Comment: @Rebecca arguably, that could be solved by allowing header redirects for all past incarnations of that user's user name. But is the malicious angle truly a real-world problem? Does Google bombing still work the way it used to five years ago? I am not convinced.

Comment: See also - [Could Stack Overflow be damaged by “URL poisoning”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67383/could-stack-overflow-be-damaged-by-url-poisoning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem you describe is caused by the URL: a slug matching redirect is done before any page is shown. So, search engines first get a 301 Moved Permanently [for the wrong URL](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155802/xoum-is-a-good-guy&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET&uak=0), if applicable. A sane search engine has no need to store the wrong URL?

(Of course, explicitly describing the links like `<a href="...">something here</a>` is a different issue.)