# Can we have friendly urls for items like our business cards?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, network-profile, profile-page

I would like to have some Stack Overflow Profile information, e.g. 'Flair' on my things like my business card.

Not a "Stack Overflow" card, promoting Stack Overflow or having it as my primary identity, but more like the back of a current business card thing, so not quite the same as [Stack Overflow business cards for regular members?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120517/stack-overflow-business-cards-for-regular-members)

I was inspired to do this at the WorldWide meeting by another member (actually a moderator) who had physically taped his profile info to a name tag card for the meetup - creative!

Obviously there is nothing to *actually* stop someone from using their profile image when they order a business cards. Or at a minimum listing their profile url.  But the flair looks so much cooler...

Anyway... This request is for a "friendly" url for my profile.  Often this is done for SEO (Search Engine Optimization) reasons, but in this case it's for the more mundane issue of actually having folks type it in correctly and many folks would find just /michael-durrant easier than /631619/michael-durrant

One aspect I've also thought (from reading the above mentioned post) is whether anyone 'should' be able to do this, for example only for 10k+ rep? I tend to think of this as somewhat self-selecting, i.e. only folks who have a pretty good reputation and are very proud of it will want to do it.  In fact that makes a good argument for the flair... that has the rep. level on it.  Of course our "v2" physical business cards could easily be electronic wireless paper with the score continually updated ;)

I've reviewed [Friendly urls for profiles and search engine pollution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82915/friendly-urls-for-profiles-and-search-engine-pollution) and I feel that Arjan has addressed the "security" issue that was raised.  I've also reviewed [Could Stack Overflow be damaged by "URL poisoning"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67383/could-stack-overflow-be-damaged-by-url-poisoning)

One final thought - I'm going to ask that folks please *consider* upvoting/downvoting what they consider to be the "right" answer.  I expect basically either a variant on a "yes" and a variant on a "no" though of course there could be "maybes", anyway, getting Mega downvotes on the question (as I experienced recently) feels more punitive than upvotes and downvotes on actual answers.  Yes I don't like reputation losses, even on meta, but also I think this question is a "fair" question, that others will ask, even if the "correct" answer is No.  Obviously imho and I'm still new here :)

Comment: A profile domain if it wasn't squatted: http://whois.domaintools.com/stack.me

Comment: These are friendly URLs, but they're *functional* friendly URLs. Not including the user ID would be a massive crazy ass pain to keep up with changing names, and *impossible* to manage because 2 people on SE can have the same name. There can be two Michael Durrants but not two /Michael-Durrants, either this would become some first-come-first serve nightmare or it would require forcing user ids to be unique, neither of which is helpful for our core goal of answering questions.

Comment: +1 Ben good point, I was only thinking of the 'change username' issue.  If accounts exist w/same name that's a major issue!  Anyway Oded provided a great solution for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select a path on [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) that will be friendly:

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/<your choice>
```

This assumes you *have* a Careers 2.0 invite...

Comment: Great Option for me.  My github account qualified me instantly!